# I am getting "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, string, class

I am getting "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'model'" on line 26. I can not figure out why? not sure how to correct?

```
 import time
 import threading 
                
    def test(name,name2):
        print(name)
        print(name2)
        car.show(name)
        car.color(name2)
        time.sleep(30) 
            
class car(): 
    def __init__(self, model, color): 
        self.model = model 
        self.color = color 
                  
def show(self): 
    print("Model is", self.model ) 
    print("color is", self.color ) 
                  
    audi = car("audi a4", "blue")
    ferrari = car("ferrari 488", "green") 
    acura = car("acura" , "black")
    BMW = car("BMW" , "blue")
    Cadillac  = car("Cadillac", "green")  
        
    f = open("/home/stuff/script/QT/car.txt", "r") #In car.txt file has car model and color list line by line
        
    threads = []  
    for x in range (5):
    name=(f.readline())
    name=name.strip()
    name2=(f.readline())
    name2=name2.strip()                              
    info = threading.Thread (target=test(name,name2))
    threads.append(info)
    info.start()
                        
    x= +x;
                      
    f.close()
```

Comment: You need to properly format your code with correct indention. Also, provide the full stacktrace (the full error message). You also need to provide a [mcve]. There are currently much in your code that doesn't seem to be used.

Comment: It seems like you never instantiate an object. You must do that before you can call `show` on an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now come to look at it your code has multiple problems.

Firstly in your test method make the following changes
Right now your car class doesn't have a color method. It only has a color field which you can access

```
def test(name,name2):
    print(name)
    print(name2)
    some_car = car(name, name2)
    some_car.show()
    print(some_car.color)
    time.sleep(30)
```

if you somehow want to pass arg to the show method use the following method signature

```
def show(self, name)
```

the first param if class method is reference to the same object.
[Refer here for more info on Python3 classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes. it seems I could not understand concept of passing arg to show method.   Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Indent your show method, Currently it is outside of the class car and hence most probably the problem is because you are passing the self param to a function and not a class method. So self is being evaluated to a string and when you are printing it using self.model it is throwing the exception

Comment: runfile('/home/stuff/script/QT/temp.py', wdir='/home/stuff/script/QT')
audi
blue
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/stuff/script/QT/temp.py", line 49, in <module>
    info = threading.Thread (target=test(name,name2))

  File "/home/stuff/script/QT/temp.py", line 15, in test
    Car.show(name)

Comment: above is my error. I do not have any error in tab issue because Spyder would pick up.

Comment: @otay No it won't as the syntax is correct and you can add a function outside the class also in python.

Answer (score 0):

you have problem in these lines:

```
car.show(name)
car.color(name2)
```

car is `class` (and btw the convention is to use Car)

`car.show` is just a function and you pass it a string,
for example 'car.show('blue')' which causes `self.model` to fail becasue `'blue'.model` is faulty.

I am pretty sure you meant to instantiate a car in your test function
with:

```
the_car = car(name, name2)
the_car.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! for correct me on class convention Car not the car.  it seems in function print(name) and print(name2) does receive the string from txt file but I can not pass in to Car.show(name). I am new at this.